# Android Studio - java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I get this error after updating my Android Studio to all new versions after 3.0 Canary 4. (I am using v3.0 cause it is much faster and there is no need to jack for Kotlin.)

It looks like there is an issue with build flow that it cannot generate or sign my APK file for both debug and release version.

I also tried deleting my `debug.keystore`, restarting AndroidStudio and system(!!!) but it didn't solve.

Here is a full Gradle log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':chris-app:packageDemoDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature

* Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':chris-app:packageDemoDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:225)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55) Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:240)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:235)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:196)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:180)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:466)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:168)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:297)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$200(SigningExtension.java:55)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$2(SigningExtension.java:175)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2099)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:871)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1161)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:172)
        at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:216)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:698)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:520)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(OutputScope.java:185)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(OutputScope.java:202)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$null$8(OutputScope.java:224) "
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.checkEntryNameValid(V1SchemeSigner.java:406)
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateManifestFile(V1SchemeSigner.java:373)
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.sign(V1SchemeSigner.java:253)
        at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:372)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:295)
        ... 13 more


BUILD FAILED in 2m 49s
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After more investigation using `gradle assemble --stacktrace` command I found that the issue is with APK zipping process:

> Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to generate v1
>   signature Error:java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
>   Error:com.android.apksig.apk.ApkFormatException: Unsupported character
>   0x0d in ZIP entry name "assets/Icon?"

There was a file named "Icon?" in my project which is a MacOS file that indicates folder's icon and it contains `CR, LF` characters inside.

I deleted the file and now everything is working fine.

This issue showed up in all versions after Android Studio Canary 4 and I report the issue to Android Studio team on this thread https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63885809

and they mentioned:

> 3.0 Canary 4 is about the time we added that "Unsupported character" check, so that's why it happens from that version forward.

They are investigating more to solve this issue and I hope this answer helps others not to waste one month not updating their Android Studio. :)

Comment: I am still seeing this with the stable Android Studio 3.0.0 release.

Comment: @JohanPaul yes, this change is here to stay! You have to find the file and remove it.

Comment: I did a Gradle build from the command line, which was successful. After this I could again build from AS 3.0 too. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JohanPaul it is true. Syncing project with Gradle files (using the relevant button on AS toolbar) helps, mostly when you switch between different build tools versions.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseini where do I find this Icon? I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I started out with lots of errors "file name must end in .xml or .png (Im using Mac OSX also) Then I started deleting a bunch of random icon files I found scattered around. Ending up getting a new error "execution failed for task ‘:app:packageDebug’ failed to generate v1 signature"

In the end, got a good advice to try Build > Clean Project and then recompile. This will force the IDE to take another look at the files and try again). If you deleted the icon files, Android Studio may need to re-index the project.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting ~/.android/debug.keystore file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33910425)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the -alias  using the same name with keystore file name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).