# "The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size" while rebuilding on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk-signing

I am facing this problem while building the project. Below is the stacktrace. I created a new keystore file for release key but didn't work.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:292)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$200(SigningExtension.java:53)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$2(SigningExtension.java:171)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2154)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:923)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1207)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:174)
at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:216)
at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:704)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:515)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$3(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:396)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to sign using signer "CERT"
at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.signManifest(V1SchemeSigner.java:295)
at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.sign(V1SchemeSigner.java:256)
at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:424)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:290)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to sign using SHA1withDSA
at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateSignatureBlock(V1SchemeSigner.java:519)
at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.signManifest(V1SchemeSigner.java:293)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
at sun.security.provider.DSA.checkKey(DSA.java:104)
at sun.security.provider.DSA.engineInitSign(DSA.java:136)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1152)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1112)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1176)
at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:527)
at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateSignatureBlock(V1SchemeSigner.java:515)
```

Followed other questions on the forum but nothing worked. Please help.
Android Studio Version - 3.2.1

**Edit**- Changing the minSdkVersion from 18 to 21 fixed the issue. But not able to figure out the real reason behind this.

Comment: I did change it from 18 to 21 as well and it worked. The other thing that I observed was that the min sdk installed in Andoid Studio was 21. Not sure if this is the problem though

Comment: I installed Android SDK 18 but then also it didn't work.

Comment: are you trying to build project in another PC or Laptop from last last  PC or Laptop ?

Comment: @MayurDabhi this could only cause the problem, in case different JDK versions would be installed to different computers... while the question does not feature different computers.

Comment: there is InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest. and InvalidKeyException for SHA-1 possible to PC or laptop change!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129415/7596740

Comment: Seeing DSA in the stack trace, it is probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248406/android-studio-errororg-gradle-tooling-buildexception-failed-to-generate-v1-s

Answer (score 5):

The error message means, that the key likely has **1024** bits strength, because it had been generated with any JDK version before JDK `8u151` - while *at least* **2048** bits key-strength are being expected:

> The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size.

The reason behind this is, that the default key-size had changed from **1024** to **2048** bits with JDK `8u151`. This change can also be found in the JRE/JDK [crypto roadmap](https://java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html) at datecode `2017-10-17`:

> Upgraded the jarsigner and keytool ‑sigalg default to SHA256withDSA and the ‑keysize default to 2048 for DSA keys.

The "Reverting Instructions" would be (which do not really apply for signage with Android Studio):

> To use a different algorithm and/or smaller key size use the ‑sigalg and ‑keysize options of keytool and jarsigner to override the current defaults. Before this change the default values were SHA1withDSA and 1024 bits.

For an APK, it is recommend to use the [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) instead of the [jarsigner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) - and there meanwhile is a [APK Signature Scheme v3](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3) (these are backwards compatible - therefore it is save not to use `v1`).

Generating a new key with *at least* **2048** bits strength should permit the `v1` (`jar`) signing. Downgrading the JDK would also be a feasible workaround (while I'd rather not suggest that).

If you've already published this key to Google Play, the best option available might be trying to migrate to [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) (the release key would be downgraded to an upload key).

---

The bottom line is, that most likely your system-wide installed version of the JDK is much older than the OpenJDK bundled with the current version of Android Studio - and so you can generate as many new keys as you want, but they won't meet the minimum security requirements. Updating the system-wide installed version of the JDK should enable you to generate keys with sufficient strength; run `java -version`, to see what you are even using to generate keys with an insufficient strength.

***or*** simply use the `... /android-studio/jre/jre/bin/keytool` to generate them.

Answer (score 5):

Generating the keystore with *keysize* length 2048 worked for me.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be caused by a wrong format of icons, there is an issue tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63885809

Run below command to see the resources that are in problem

```
./gradlew assemble --stacktrace
```

Find the logs like below:

> Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to generate v1 signature Error:java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature Error:com.android.apksig.apk.ApkFormatException: Unsupported character xxxx in ZIP entry name "xxxx/xxx?"

Try to delete the file or replace with a new one.

Comment: Couldn't find any such logs. Sorry for the late reply.